# Angular2+ scope of services

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

I have an angular2+ app, with the following structure: App Component -> Login Component and a Main Component. The main component is part of a lazy loaded module (Main Module), accessible only after successful log in.

I want to have a userService within the Main Module that is not accessible outside it. I believe that if the module is lazy loaded, this service will not be accessible outside the lazy module. However, if I go back to the login screen (after logging out) and then re-enter the Main Module, I have noticed that the service is not reinstatiated because the service did not get destroyed when I went back to login. From my understanding this is because lazy modules are not unloaded.

My other solution for scoping the service to the part of the app after the login screen was to provide it within Main Component rather than in Main Module. This way it would be accessible to all its child components using hierarchical dependency injection. This seems to be working for the most part, however I'm not able to access it in route resolvers (and I think the same issue would occur in other services) if I try to inject userService into them. I get the static injector error stating no provider. How would I provide a local component service to another local component service or a route resolver?

EDIT:

I noticed for the second part, services that are provided in the same component can all inject each other. The problem is with my route resolvers. To my understanding, they need to be provided in a module so that they are accessible by the routing module. However, this means that they are not part of the hierarchy of my Main Component and can thus not access any services provided by this component. Is there any way around this? Route resolvers are somewhat always associated with components so it seems strange that there is no way to link them with the hierarchy of a component

Comment: Share your code for more detail

Comment: @HiteshKansagara not really sure which part of the code to share. This is more of an architectural question

Comment: Related: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21028

Comment: You have to write services in providers part of your main module to access from everywhere in your app

Comment: Thank you both. I understand that but how do I destroy the service so that its memory is released when I navigate out of Main Component?